# Going through each line in a text-file and adding to listbox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, listbox, text-files

I have a text-file (customers.txt) which I am trying to extract certain pieces of Information from. I have split up each line in the text-file using commas and in doing so allowing me to place parts of a line in a list-box(lstReportsUnresolved). However, I am having difficulties creating a loop to do this for each line in the text file, adding parts from each line to the list-box.

The code:

```
Private Sub btnUnresolved_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUnresolved.Click

    Dim reader As New StreamReader("customers.txt")

        Dim data As String()

    data = reader.ReadLine().Split(",")


        If data(18) = "No" Then
            lstReportsUnresolved.Items.Add(data(17))

        End If
        If data(20) = "No" Then
            lstReportsUnresolved.Items.Add(data(19))

        End If
        If data(22) = "No" Then
            lstReportsUnresolved.Items.Add(data(21))

        End If
        If data(24) = "No" Then
            lstReportsUnresolved.Items.Add(data(23))

        End If

 End Sub
```

I have tried adding

```
For Each Line As String In File.ReadLines("customers.txt")
Next
```

with the if statements between them but this just seems to add the sections from the first line to the list-box three times.

I'm am new to VB so apologies if I am making a silly mistake.

Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: Have you also splitted every line in the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you also splitted every line in the loop?

```
For Each line As String In File.ReadLines("customers.txt")
    Dim data As String() = line.Split(",")
    If data(18) = "No" Then
        lstReportsUnresolved.Items.Add(data(17))
    End If
    ' .... '
Next
```

However, using `,` as delimiter is error-prone because the values might also contain commas.